# Add "name" to mailing list

Tags: email, solspace-freeform

Im using Freeform to submit a form which adds the sender automatically to a mailing list.

Does anyone know if it is possible to add "name" to a mailing list? One would have though this should be a built-in feature be alas.

Thanks for any pointers.

Kippi

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't. The internal mailing list just handles email addresses. It's not meant to be a full Email Management System, just a method for you to provide general communications via ExpressionEngine.

ExpressionEngine integrates well with numerous other Email Management Solutions (EMS). You can use *MailChimp, Campaign Monitor, Emma, Constant Contact*, etc.

[MailChimp](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=MailChimp&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2) and [Campaign Monitor](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=Campaign%20Monitor&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2) have add-ons that allow extended integration, but generally speaking as long as the EMS provides javascript embed forms, you can use any solution you like. Using a full fledge EMS provides a lot more benefits, since you can allow segmentation, auto responders, etc.

Using EE's **Mailing List Module** doesn't really allow for list segmentation. You can create multiple lists, so people could sign-up to receive say 'event notices' vs 'general announcements', but it can be hard enough to get someone to sign-up for one mailing let alone two or three.